# Hiding Ad view when no ad is received then showing again after

Tags: ios, ios5, admob, iad

I have setup a test application using Admob Mediation service. I have an issue that when an error occurs and is handled by a method if I hide the banner View it causes no further ad requests to occur, possibly due to this 'hidden status'.

What I can do is sleep within the error method for a certain amount of time then request again, however this isn't the best method... I am guessing this would lock up some process and potentially other user input whilst sleepng? I am not sure of this as the app only includes ads so cannot test.

Here are my methods...

```
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error;
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    bannerView_.hidden = YES;
    sleep(59);
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view;
{
    NSLog(@"Ad Received");
    bannerView_.hidden = NO;
}
```

I am looking for the best way to either:
1. Hide the view when no ad is returned, but ensure requests continue and the ad view is shown again once an ad is received.
2. Use a loop in the error method to handle requesting again until successful and not locking up anything else.

Only being tested on simulator at the moment, if any difference is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use performSelector to make an asynchronous call instead of using sleep because sleep will block your thread. So this is implemented as in the 1st way you mentioned.

```
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error;
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    bannerView_.hidden = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(repeatAdRequest) withObject:nil afterDelay:60.0];
}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view;
{
    NSLog(@"Ad Received");
    bannerView_.hidden = NO;
}

-(void) repeatAdRequest
{
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works,however I am still having some issue. I'm using iAd and Admob.For testing I am using 100% iAd(for now)as iAd throws a lot of errors for testing.Once an error occurs, using the above to request for a new ad,I am just seeing constant errors,after the first occurs.Is this expected?once 1 error happens it will continue,seems strange?I changed the above to be 1 second for each request but the same error which is this "Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks."

Comment: It is a strange error as I do receive ads up until this point, so it doesn't actually make that much sense...

Comment: I didn't notice this behavior before but it might be because the test errors are generated per run instead of per iad request. Digging into apple's documentation i can recommend you a manual way to test if such is the case, from apple documentation: "... to assist you in validating your implementation, the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test your error handling code. You can also test your error handling support manually by turning your device’s wireless capability off."

Comment: So maybe you can manually receive an error by turning off the wifi and turning it on again to see if your method works. Also it turns out iAd's default behavior is to repeat ad request if an error occurred. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW10 . So you may not need to implement anything at all, but you may still use it in the case where iAd is not available and you want to switch to admob or vice-versa. Hope it helps

Comment: Although this is what iAd does per the documentation, it doesnt seem to when incorporated from Admob Mediation, it seemed to end requesting.

Comment: Note, I am unable to award the bounty, but it should automatically award to you. Clicking on the bounty under answer tick does nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

make addview a subview of another blank uiview.

In adview didfail, hide the view and not the adview
and in recieve show the view again.

Comment: Yes, but this wouldnt actually hide the view when no ad is received. This means the screen space for the AdView would still be on screen, which is not what I want if an error occurs or no ad is received...